# composer install / composer upgrade can't clone git repo

Tags: wordpress, docker, composer-php

Inside a docker i have a composer.json that is meant to create a localhost with a specific installation of wordpress, i'm trying to install with its .git so i run `composer install --prefer-source` but it seems that it is not able to clone anything, same for a `composer update --prefer-source` i end up with something like this :

```
      - Syncing johnpbloch/wordpress-core (5.9.3) into cache
  - Syncing mars/mars-wp-blocks (dev-master fa67b2e) into cache
  - Syncing mars/wp-artixor (dev-master 79fc740) into cache
  - Syncing mars/wp-safe-theme (dev-master 4d8b41e) into cache
  - Upgrading google/apiclient-services (v0.289.0 => v0.290.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading google/apiclient (v2.13.0 => v2.13.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading aws/aws-sdk-php (3.261.7 => 3.261.12): Extracting archive
  - Installing johnpbloch/wordpress-core (5.9.3): Cloning 455d38c7b7bcdce3e0a1c6108eccca8de1860361 from cache
    Install of johnpbloch/wordpress-core failed
  - Installing mars/mars-wp-blocks (dev-master fa67b2e): Cloning fa67b2e0b443103f3a3640e8d7ad4705d36c328d from cache
    Install of mars/mars-wp-blocks failed
  - Installing mars/wp-artixor (dev-master 79fc740): Cloning 79fc74046c32c9f21c03b0febd4bb13779d455e7 from cache
    Install of mars/wp-artixor failed
  - Upgrading myclabs/php-enum (1.7.7 => 1.8.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing mars/wp-safe-theme (dev-master 4d8b41e): Cloning 4d8b41e1b51e88e4c5ea253c7a5137c82147d7f9 from cache
    Install of mars/wp-safe-theme failed
  - Upgrading wp-cli/entity-command (v2.4.1 => v2.4.2): Extracting archive
 4/5 [======================>-----]  80% 10 mins
```

it gets stuck forever at 4/5 with a fail to install everything that is being cloned, my github token is set and works, this is the result of the `composer diagnose` :

```
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK git version 2.30.2
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com oauth access: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: You are not running the latest stable version, run `composer self-update` to update (2.4.3 => 2.5.4)
Composer version: 2.4.3
PHP version: 7.3.33
PHP binary path: /usr/local/bin/php
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
cURL version: 7.74.0 libz 1.2.11 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1n
zip: extension present, unzip present, 7-Zip not available
```

composer install works perfectly and composer update also but when i add the --prefer-source it doesn't work anymore

i tried to reinstall everything, regenerate github token, clear the cache, remove vendor and do `composer update --prefer-source` still getting the same problem

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Would this work with a more current PHP version (7.3 is EOL since more than a year!), or a more current Composer version, or outside a Docker container?

Comment: i tried to clear the cache remove the vendor directory remove the web/temp-wordpress-dir, reinstall docker, reset new github tokens but nothing seems to change that,. 
i can't really change the php version, it's meant to be the same as we have in prod 
i will try to update the composer version to see if i still have the same problem
I don't have the rights dependencies that are, there are some outdated things needed so i can't use the composer outside of the docker

Comment: Well i do get another error, it fails to Install of composer/installers because the destination path '/home/dev/apache-shared-data/www/vendor/composer/installers' already exists and is not an empty directory but the directory doesn't exists when the composer install --prefer-source isn't running, also removed the vendor dir but didn't changed the problem

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: _"Extracting archive"_ suggests it is *not* git related. Do `composer -n --profile -vvv install --prefer-source` (non-interactive (-n), with profiling (that is timing / memory --profile) and very verbose (-vvv = debug)) to obtain more details.